# Full outer join with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: one containing data with end of year information and another with end of quarter information for multiple products. I want to join them so that each row has information for one product per day:

```
product_id | annual or quarter date | annual_info | quarterly_info
```

A full outer join like:

```
select a.date, b.date from 
annual_table a
full outer join quarterly_table q on q.product_id = a.product_id and q.date = a.date
```

does not work, since it only gives me the end of year dates:

```
date       |date       |
-----------|-----------|
1996-12-31 |           |
1997-12-31 |           |
1998-12-31 |           |
1999-12-31 |           |
2000-12-31 |           |
2001-12-31 |           |
2002-12-31 |2002-12-31 |
2003-12-31 |2003-12-31 |
2004-12-31 |2004-12-31 |
2005-12-31 |2005-12-31 |
2006-12-31 |2006-12-31 |
2007-12-31 |2007-12-31 |
```

I thought a full outer join was also supposed to include rows that did not have a counterpart in the other table.

Annual table:

```
product_id  |date       |sales            |
------------|-----------|-----------------|
GHPRRB-S-US |1996-12-31 |48.5933895113959 |
GHPRRB-S-US |1997-12-31 |177.526458150594 |
GHPRRB-S-US |1998-12-31 |184.663          |
GHPRRB-S-US |1999-12-31 |276.333          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2000-12-31 |440.285          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2001-12-31 |298.466          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2002-12-31 |301.962          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2003-12-31 |391.93           |
GHPRRB-S-US |2004-12-31 |621.138          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2005-12-31 |420.929          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2006-12-31 |517.706          |
GHPRRB-S-US |2007-12-31 |475.089          |
```

Quarterly table:

```
product_id  |date       |sales   |
------------|-----------|--------|
GHPRRB-S-US |2002-03-31 |68.97   |
GHPRRB-S-US |2002-06-30 |77.702  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2002-09-30 |80.123  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2002-12-31 |75.167  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2003-03-31 |68.97   |
GHPRRB-S-US |2003-06-30 |91.701  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2003-09-30 |103.085 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2003-12-31 |125.926 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2004-03-31 |130.28  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2004-06-30 |179.916 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2004-09-30 |163.52  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2004-12-31 |148.129 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2005-03-31 |115.843 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2005-06-30 |122.392 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2005-09-30 |124.545 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2005-12-31 |124.641 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2006-03-31 |127.33  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2006-06-30 |143.873 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2006-09-30 |136.842 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2006-12-31 |109.661 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2007-03-31 |97.253  |
GHPRRB-S-US |2007-06-30 |114.988 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2007-09-30 |128.189 |
GHPRRB-S-US |2007-12-31 |134.659 |
```

Comment: Are you _certain_ you are only getting the end of year dates?  I suspect you have _two_ date columns, one with the annual date and one with the quarter date since you are doing `SELECT *`  If you want to have both dates in one column then you can't do `SELECT *`.

Comment: "I thought a full outer join was also supposed to include rows that did not have a counterpart in the other table."  A full outer join includes all records from both tables aligning those that match in both to the same line based on join criteria.  Are you sure you don't have a WHERE clause that is eliminating data from the join?  (can't have a where clause against the data or the NULL records will be removed! making it a left or right join!) you'd have to move the limits to the join it self so the where is applied before the join; thereby allowing the null values to remain. Post actual Query!

Comment: Are they Dates or date times?  maybe time is being included but not displayed! (What's the data type for date in both tables?)  maybe a : `on  q.product_id = a.product_id  and CONVERT(date, a.date) =CONVERT(date, b.date)`

Comment: You could _temporarily_ add a `WHERE a.date IS NULL` to see if the quarterly results are there.

Comment: @xQbert I do have a `where a.product_id = 'GHPRRB-S-US'` and that was the issue XD

Comment: It would.  as the a.product_ID would eliminate all the null matches from the 2nd table.   Keep in mind the where executes AFTER the join.  so any NULL records (because no product/date matches in 1st) from the 2nd table would be excluded.  I suggest focusing in on 1 product for 3 days that you know the product exists in both tables with the same date, 1 situation where product is in both tables but missing a date in A, and 1 situation where product is in both tables but missing a date in B.

Comment: can you include what your desired result is with the example data set?  "I want to join them so that each row has information for one product per day:" this sounds more like a UNION.  If the case that the date is in the Annual and in the Quarterly which Sales Figure do you want Annual or Quarterly?  It would also seem that the Quarterly table includes the Annual just aggregated to a different level would that be true?

Answer (score 3):

Just to close this out:
I had a where clause that was restricting the results. I pushed the WHERE clause into the ON conditions and I was able to see all the results.

Thanks to @xQbert for spotting it!

Comment: glad you got the help, I would suggest deleting the question if it ended up being an easy syntax issue as it won't provide much insight to others.

Comment: This is because the JOIN occurs before the where clause.   The null records are generated on the Full outer join, then the NULL records are eliminated because of your where clause!  Moving limit to the join ensures the filter is applied before the join thus allowing the unmatched records from the full outer join to remain.  Now also note, if you only are looking at product `GHPRRB-S-US` you would also need B.product_ID = that value... otherwise you'll get more than you want due to the full outer join!